# Individual/manual page numbers for table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

Question answered

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\part{List of Figures} %(required page number "i")
\part{List of Tables}  %(required page number "ii")
\part{Abbreviations}   %(required page number "iii")
\part{Declaration}     %(required page number "iv")

\section{Introdution} 


\subsection{Start}   %(required page number "1")
\subsection{Start2}      %(required page number "3")
\subsection{Start 3} %(required page number "5")
\subsection{Start 4} %(required page number "8")

\section{Literature Review} %(required page number "10")

\subsection{Focal theories} %(required page number "10")

\subsubsection{Theorie 1} %(required page number "11")

\paragraph{Theorie 1a} %(required page number "11")
\paragrap{Theorie 1b} %(required page number "25")
\paragraph{Theorie 1c} %(required page number "28")

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use package [`blindtext`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/blindtext) for creating dummy pages.  Then your resulting ToC shows the needed page numbers ...  BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Or you could just for this occasion add a `\setcounter{page}{#reqiredpageno}` before the section commands.

Comment: Shouldn't the LoF be "ii"? Doesn't the ToC should be counted, but not numbered, as well?

Answer (score 2):

Prepare two files.

### First file `faketoc.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{tocloft}

%\includeonly{}
\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\include{\jobname-include}

\end{document}
```

### Second file `faketoc-include.tex`

```
\pagenumbering{roman}

\part{List of Figures} %(required page number "i")
\clearpage
\part{List of Tables}  %(required page number "ii")
\clearpage
\part{Abbreviations}   %(required page number "iii")
\clearpage
\part{Declaration}     %(required page number "iv")
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

%\setcounter{page}{1} %redundant
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Research problem}   %(required page number "1")
\clearpage\setcounter{page}{3}
\subsection{Research aims}      %(required page number "3")
\clearpage\setcounter{page}{5}
\subsection{Research questions} %(required page number "5")
\clearpage\setcounter{page}{8}
\subsection{Organisation of the dissertation} %(required page number "8")

\clearpage\setcounter{page}{10}
\section{Literature Review} %(required page number "10")

\subsection{Focal theories} %(required page number "10")

\clearpage\setcounter{page}{11}
\subsubsection{The five competitive forces} %(required page number "11")

\paragraph{Definition and concept} %(required page number "11")
\clearpage\setcounter{page}{25}
\paragraph{Critical review} %(required page number "25")
\clearpage\setcounter{page}{28}
\paragraph{Linkage to competitive advantage} %(required page number "28")
```

### Procedure

1. Compile `faketoc.tex`
2. Remove the `%` before `\includeonly{}`
3. Compile again `faketoc.tex`

The result will be a PDF containing only the table of contents

[image]